# primefaces pe:exporter showing the row number as String "#{rowIndex+1}" instead of its value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using rowIndexVar in my dataTable to add a columns showing the row number . It's working when displaying my dataTable but when downloading via pe:exporter, the numbers are shown as String "#{rowIndex+1}" instead of their values.
here is my code :

```
                                                        <p:dataTable var="table"
                                                            value="#{myBean.dataTable}"
                                                            id="results" scrollable="true" scrollRows="10"
                                                            rowIndexVar="rowIndex" scrollHeight="300"
                                                            resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">

                                                            <p:column headerText="obs" width="30"
                                                                style="text-align: center">
                                                                #{rowIndex+1}
                                                            </p:column>

                                                           <p:columns var="data" columnIndexVar="index"
                                                                value="#{myBean.dataColumns}">
                                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                                    <h:outputText value="#{data}" />
                                                                </f:facet>
                                                                <h:outputText value="#{table[index]}" />
                                                            </p:columns>

                                                        </p:dataTable>

                                                   <!--*******Export******* -->
                                                    <p:spacer height="10" />
                                                    <h:panelGrid width="100">
                                                        <p:panel header="Exporter">
                                                            <p:row>
                                                                <p:column>
                                                                    <p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false">
                                                                        <p:graphicImage
                                                                            value="/resources/images/icons/export/pdf.png" />
                                                                        <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="results"
                                                                            fileName="table" />
                                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                                </p:column>
                                                                <p:column>
                                                                    <p:commandLink id="excel" ajax="false">
                                                                        <p:graphicImage
                                                                            value="/resources/images/icons/export/excel.png" />
                                                                        <pe:exporter type="xlsx" target="results"
                                                                            fileName="table" />
                                                                    </p:commandLink>
                                                                </p:column>
                                                            </p:row>
                                                        </p:panel>
                                                    </h:panelGrid>
```

BTW, resizable columns doesnt work, if you have an idea, it will be great.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<p:dataTable var="table"
  rowIndexVar="rowIndex" >

     <p:column headerText="obs" width="30"
       style="text-align: center">
    <h:outputText value= "#{rowIndex+1}"/>.
```